# Why the difference between these two numpy array assignments?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

The following was run on an iPython Notebook.

```
import numpy as np
    
m = 3
A = np.array([[0.6, 0.5, 0.3]])
Y = np.zeros((1,m))

Y[:] = A > 0.5
```

`# THIS GIVES: predictions = [[ 1.  1.  0.]]`

```
Y = A > 0.5
```

`# WHERE AS THIS GIVES: predictions = [[ True  True  False]]`

However the first result occurs only on the Jupyter iPython notebook's interpreter, while everywhere else(in Python 3.8) both statements give the second result only. Kindly explain why the different results..

Comment: "However the first result occurs only on the Jupyter iPython notebook's interpreter, while everywhere else(in Python 3.8) both statements give the second result only." Nope, not true at all. The behavior is the same everywhere. Anyway, this is because `Y` has `dtype=np.float64` by default (or perhaps `np.float32` depending on your system architecture, in any case it is a floating point dtype).

Comment: If it depends on the system architecture only, then why does the iPython Notebook give two different results?

Comment: Update: you are right, I checked this by passing ```dtype=float32``` on my system, the behavour is as expected.